# Why serialization in djano rest framework is costly in terms of performance?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

```
class SalesDataSummaryViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    queryset=SalesDataSummary.objects.all()
    serializer_class=SalesDataSummarySerializer

    response = writeSerializedDataToCSV(response, headers, fieldnames,serializer_class.data)
```

I am trying to convert response into csv and it takes around 5 minutes for 25k records, Where as the below code takes around 15-18 seconds, Here I am manually looping and creating a json.

```
class SalesDataSummaryViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
        queryset=SalesDataSummary.objects.all()
        queryset_list=[]
        for data in queryset:
            queryset_dict={}
            queryset_dict['number']=data.number
            queryset_dict['name']=data.name 
            queryset_dict['time']=data.time
            queryset_dict['code']=data.code
            queryset_dict['uuid']=data.uuid
            queryset_list.append(queryset_dict)
            
        response = writeSerializedDataToCSV(response, headers, fieldnames,queryset_list)
```

**Edit**

Adding Serializer

```
class SalesDataSummarySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    
    class Meta:
        model = SalesDataSummary
        fields='__all__'

    def to_representation(self, instance):
    response = super().to_representation(instance)
    business_obj=  Business.objects.filter(pk=instance.business_id).first()
    response['business']= BusinessSerializer(business_obj).data
    return response
```

Comment: Can you show your serializer?

Comment: Sure,I will edit and add the serializer

Comment: It could be some other piece of code that causes this. Can you share your whole view?

Comment: @bdbd I have updated the serializer and this is my final code.

Comment: And there in your last edit lies the reason for the slowness. In `SalesDataSummarySerializer `, for each instance of `SalesDataSummary`, you are doing one database call with `Business.objects.filter(pk=instance.business_id).first()`

Comment: Ohh okay alright, I got it. So for 25k products 25k db calls are made. Thank you @bdbd